# MYSQL Problem: it erases all the tables and before it matters

Tags: mysql, database, bash

I have a strange problem with MySLQ.
previously the dump file had the following structure->

```
   CASE A
____________
DROP TALBE A
IMPORT TABLE A
DROP TABLE B
IMPORTA TABLE B
DROP TABLE C
IMPORT TABLE C
```

......

Currently ->

```
   CASE B
____________
DELETE TABLE A
DELETE TABLE B
DELETE TABLE C
IMPORT TABLE A
IMPORT TABLE B
IMPORT TABLE C
```

........

The only difference between the import script between case one and two is this:
CASE A:

```
DB_PORT=xxx
DB_HOST=xxx
DB_NAME=xxx
PROJECT=xxx
DB_SOURCE=xxx
BACKUP_FILE="$xxx/xxx/${xxx}_${xxx}_${xxx}.sql.gz.gpg"
LOG_FILE=$xxx/xxx/$xxx/xxx



mysqldump -S /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.sock -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME | gzip |  gpg -e -r 'xxx <xxxxxx> $BACKUP_FILE
export -f xxx
find $xxx/xxx/ -name "${xxx}_${xxx}_*" -type f -exec /bin/bash -c 'xxx "{}"' \;

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
```

CASE B:

```
    #!/bin/bash




    HOME="/xxx/xxx"
    DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
    DATE_LOGS=`date +%Y-%m`
    PROJECT=xxx
    DB_SOURCE=xxx
    DB_FILE="$xxx/xxx/${xxx}_${xxx}_${xxx}.sql"
    DB_FILE_COMPRESS="$xxx/xxx/${xxx}_${xxx}_${xxx}.sql.gz"
    DB_FILE_ENCRYPT="$xxxx/xxx/${xxx}_${xxx}_${xxx}.sql.gz.gpg"
    LOG_FILE=$xxx/xxx/$xxx/xxx
    PASSWORD=xxx
    USER=xxx
    DATABASE=xxx
    EXCLUDED_TABLES=(
    A 
    B 
    C
    D
    F
    )


    IGNORED_TABLES_STRING=''
    for TABLE in "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[@]}"
    do :
       IGNORED_TABLES_STRING+=" --ignore-table=${DATABASE}.${TABLE}"
    done


mysqldump -S /xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxxx.sock --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --single-transaction --no-data ${DATABASE} > ${DB_FILE}

    echo "Dump content"
    mysqldump -S /xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxxx.sock  --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} ${DATABASE} --no-create-info ${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} >> ${DB_FILE}
    gzip ${DB_FILE}
    gpg -e -r 'xxx ' ${DB_FILE_COMPRESS}

    rm ${DB_FILE_COMPRESS}

    export -f xxx
    find $HOME/bdbackups/ -name "${PROJECT}_${DB_SOURCE}_*" -type f -exec /bin/bash -c 'xxx "{}"' \;

    DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
```

really the only difference is that CASE B ignores 5 tables while CASE A DOES NOT.

Thank you very much for reading me and if anyone has any ideas I will thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In case B you have number of tables which are excluded (--ignore-table) added, so if you want them to be dropped - just remove those lines of code (with IGNORED_TABLES_STRING). That's why mysqldump has added DELETE command (it just removes all rows)

Comment: Yes, but I need the parameter (--ignore-table) to be present that reduces the capacity of the database

Comment: So, you want to save disk space? --ignore-table is a way to go, but mysqldump won't dump those tables meaning possible loss of data so you would rather try incremental backups - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-methods.html, section Making Incremental Backups by Enabling the Binary Log

Comment: I ignore these tables because developers can not use the database more quickly.

Comment: Well, performance is another part of story. You should think about correct indexes in database and/or partitioning